# Is cherrypy Python3-compatible yet?

Tags: python, cherrypy

Does cherrypy support Python3 yet? What other web frameworks out there support Python 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The website of [Cherrypy 3.2](http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/WhatsNewIn32) says that it runs on Python 3! So there you go. WSGI is not settled for Python3 yet, so you wont find the WSGI compliant frameworks (django,web.py) for python3 yet. The cherrypy, I assume takes the fastcgi route.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is update 1.01 WSGI - which introduce some changes with backwards compatibility on client side (only a little changes from server site).
So all frameworks which was WSGI compliant are compliant WSGI 1.01 and python3. 
HTTP Servers which make update to the WSGI interface can run any WSGI 1 and 1.01 application on python3 and python2.

See more on [PEP 3333](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/)
The update was accepted on 14-15 january (from python mailing list)

Answer (score 0):

I've been running a CherryPy website with Python 3 for a few months now and it works well, but you have to use the code from the python3 branch of the repository because CherryPy 3.2 isn't released yet.

Answer (score 0):

I really like [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org) and then for production, i run Bottle with Cherrypy

It's really simple. just pip3 install both and then run your bottle app with cherrypy, like:

```
app.run(host='localhost',
    port=8080,
    server='cherrypy',
    reloader=True,
    debug=False)
```